# Using Laravel Scopes on Pivot Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

It seems the pivot models are not being used during Eloquent query from the Parent Class.

Let's say that I have a `Teacher` Model and `Student` Model. In which we have a rule where teacher has many students and students has many teacher.

by default, I needed to return all the students who are active only. So by adding a `wherePivot('active', true)` I able to get the list of active through only when using `$teacher->students()->get()`

This is my Teacher Model and my TeachStudent Pivot Model looks like

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
   public function students()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)
          ->using(TeacherStudent::class)
          ->wherePivot('active', true)
   }
}



    class TeacherStudent extends Pivot implements Sortable
    {
        use SortableTrait;

        /**
         * The "booting" method of the model.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            static::addGlobalScope('customScope', function ($query) {
                // THIS WILL NOT WORK
            });
        }

        public function scopeWithInActive()
        {  
            // THIS WILL NOT WORK
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to list all students who are regardless of active or inactive, so that on my UI, I can toggle the `active` status.

Is this achievable?

`$teacher->students()->withInActive()->get();`

Comment: I believe the `with` is your issue since Laravel will look for a Relationship. Replace your scope by `public function scopeIncludeInactive()`

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheHubert,still doesn't work, and the error refers to the `Student`  class

Comment: I see - why don't create another relationship `public function allStudents()` that doesn't filter your active status?

Comment: I was planning to move the `wherePivot` to another scope so that I can control the query through spatie's query builder.